# preg_match - simple issue with trying to get sequence of digits

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to do a fairly simple extraction in PHP:

```
$empAward = 'AMW10';
if (preg_match("/\w+(\d+)/",$empAward,$matches)) {
    $level = $matches[1]; // Wanted '10', but getting '0'
}
echo "Level is " . $level . "\n";
```

I was hoping my regex would capture the last 2 digits, however it appears to grab only the last digit, in this case 0. I wanted to get 10.
Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong here? I though the specification of \d+ would keep going till it got hold of all digits, but it just gets the last character alone. Could this be something to do with being 'greedy' or whatever it's opposite is ('generous'?!)

Thanks guys
Pete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex fails to match because `\w` matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and \d matches `[0-9]` (given we're not in unicode mode). So basically whats happening here, since `\w` also matches digits, is that the engine sees the token, which is also greedy, and matches everything (the entire string). It then notices the `\d+`, whereby it has to backtrack one step and attempt the pattern again. `\w` will then match `AMW1` and `\d+` will then successfully match `0`. To the engine, this is completely fine, as it satisfies the expression. But clearly it doesn't do the trick for you.

What you should do instead is to define your pattern a little better. You have a couple alternatives:

1. Make sure there is no digit before the digits we want to match `/[a-z](\d+)/i` or `/\D(\d+)/` (there are many derivatives...)
2. Or if it's a fixed value you want to receive, you can specify the length of the digits the engine should grab, thus making sure you get the correct result: `/\w+(\d{2})/` (once again, many derivatives...)

Either way, with all this said, I'm quite sure you'll figure it out :)

Comment: Thanks Lindrian, I did figure it out just after I posted the question when I suspected \w+ captured digits too (as per your [a-zA-Z-0-9_] pattern. Good explanation.

Comment: @Pete855217: You can always stick your expression into www.regex101.com and have it explained automatically. Then it's low risk of errors like these :)

Comment: You can use a lazy quantifier to give the priority to the second part of the pattern: `\w+?(\d+)`

Comment: Thanks Casimir - I never quite understood the use of the lazy ?, that explains it.

Comment: @Pete855217: Greedy will grab as much as possible, lazy as little as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Here is working example and with your solution to get last 2 character

```
$empAward = 'AMW10';
preg_match('#[^W]+$#D', $empAward, $match);
echo "Output : ". $match[0]; // 10
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Output : 10
```

Comment: Thanks once again @DevZer0

Comment: Can I ask DevZer0 what do you mean by too specific ie. is it too literally tied to the example subject (AMW10)?

Comment: +1 for the D option (that I never think to use). but it is a too specific pattern...

Answer (score 1):

Ah I think I figured it out.

The regex that does work is:

```
/[A-Za-z](\d+)/
```

As I understand it, the regex `\w+` matched alpha **and** numbers, up till the numeric regex `(\d+)`, leaving that last regex with only one character to capture. Is that the correct interpretation of `\w+` ?

Sorry to come back to this answer so quickly, I should have experimented more!

Answer (score 0):

Use this one

```
preg_match("/\w(\d+)+$/",$empAward,$matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this pattern:

```
"/[a-z]+(\d+)/i"


$empAward = 'AMW10';
if (preg_match("/[a-z]+(\d+)/i",$empAward,$matches)) {
    $level = $matches[1]; // Wanted '10', but getting '0'
}
echo "Level is " . $level . "\n";//Level is 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use This :
    if(preg_match("/[A-Za-z](\d+)/",$empAward,$matches)) {
    $level = $matches[1]; // Wanted '10', but getting '0'
    }
    echo "Level is " . $level . "\n";//Level is 10

Output : 
Level is 10
```